# difference between importing modules and routes in app module or just in the other modules?

Tags: angular, routes

normally I would create an app with modular design, creating different modules and importing them in my app module and declaring them in my `app-routing.module`.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'patients', canActivate:[AuthGuard], loadChildren: () => import('../app/modules/patients/patients.module').then(m => m.PatientsModule)
    },
    {
        path: 'menu', canActivate:[AuthGuard], loadChildren:() => import('../app/modules/menu/menus.module').then(m => m.MenusModule)
    },
    {
        path: 'login', loadChildren: () => import('../app/modules/login/login.module').then(m => m.UsersLoginModule)
    }
];
```

and after in those modules it's routes.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'test',
        component: TestComponent
    }
];
```

Something like that, but i just learned that I don't need that, that I could just declare the routes directly in `LoginModule` for example.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'login/test',
        component: TestComponent
    }
];
```

Does it make any difference or has any benefit if I do the `loadChildren` in my `app-routing.module`?

Comment: Yes. Separating them allows Angular to lazy load each module. This improves performance of most apps by only loading in resources as needed instead of front loading everything when your visitors arrive at your site.

Comment: @daddygames but my question is if should I do the `loadChildren` in my app-`routing.module` or just create the routes in each module?

Comment: `loadChildren` is the lazy loading. Keep that in `app-routing.module` and define your routes inside each sub-module.